# Removing css class on .focusout

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have a form on a web page that does a validation check before doing a post back to my server. The validation works well and applies a custom CSS class of `ErrorControl` to any input fields when needed.

What I want to accomplish is when a user goes to correct their mistake, they are given immediate feed back that the input is acceptable. I'm using `.focusout` to accomplish this.

Here is my form

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Donations</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" HeaderText="There were errors on the page: " />
        <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="email1" ControlToCompare="email2" ErrorMessage="Emails don't match"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="firstname" ErrorMessage="First name is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="John" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="lastname" ErrorMessage="Last name is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Doe" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="address1" ErrorMessage="Address 1 is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="address1">Address 1</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="address1" name="address1" placeholder="" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="address2">Address 2 (optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="address2" name="address2" placeholder="Apt / Suite #" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="city" ErrorMessage="City is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="city" name="city" placeholder="" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="state" ErrorMessage="State is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="state">State</label>
                    <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="state" name="state">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="NY">New York</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="zip" ErrorMessage="Zip code is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="city">Zip</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="phone" ErrorMessage="Phone number is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="">Phone #</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" runat="server" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="email1" ErrorMessage="Email is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="email1">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" runat="server" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="email2" ErrorMessage="Email confirmation is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="email2">Confirm Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" runat="server" id="email2" name="email1" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cold-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="amount" ErrorMessage="Please enter a dollar amount">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <label class="control-label" for="amount">Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" runat="server" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="$" />
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-right" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit Form" />
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have `asp:requiredvalidator` on the form and I have some javascript that gives them a custom css class when they don't validate.

The next step is to remove the class of `ErrorControl` immediately after the input loses focus.

I've written this javascript that meets the conditionals, but fails to actually remove the class. So I believe there is literally only 1 wrong line of code.

Here is that javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".panel-body").focusout(function (e) {
            var id = e.target.id;
            if (id == "firstname" || id == "lastname") {
                alert("First if hit");
                if (e.target.value != "") {
                    alert("second if hit");
                    $(id).removeClass("ErrorControl");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I would be happy to put the form on JSFiddle if that would help, but obviously my `asp:requiredValidator` code wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `removeClass` on `$(id)`, which evaluates to something like `$("firstname")`. Selecting an element by ID in JQuery requires a preceding `#`, so what you'd actually want is `$("#firstname")`.

Try this instead:

```
$("#"+id).removeClass("ErrorControl");
```

Comment: Ahhh! it seems so obvious! Thank you very much. I will accept answer when the timer allows me to do so.

Comment: @onTheInternet Happy to help!